# I'm trying to insert an image of pancakes into a <textinput> element, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how to code this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image

I need to insert a picture of pancakes into the below code so that it shows up above all of the  pages. This is using javascript. How do I program this? None of the code I'm using is working :( I've tried adding it to the <View style component, but that doesn't work, and then trying to import a png from my laptop isn't working either.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Recipe = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [word, setWord] = useState(" ");
    const [definition, setDefinition] = useState(" ");


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
       placeholder = "Ingredients"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "1 1/2 cup flour" 
      />
      <TextInput
       placeholder = "3 1/2 teaspoons baking powder"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "1 Tablespoon sugar" 
      />
      <TextInput
       placeholder = "pinch salt"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "1 1/4 cup milk" 
      />
      <TextInput
       placeholder = "3 tablespoons butter"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "1 egg" 
      />
       <TextInput
      placeholder = " " 
      />
       <TextInput
      placeholder = "Directions:" 
      />
       <TextInput
      placeholder = " " 
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Step 1"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Sift flour, baking powder, sugar, and salt together in a"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "large bowl. Make a well in the center and add milk,"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "melted butter, and egg; mix until smooth."
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = " "
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Step 2"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Heat a lightly oiled griddle or pan over medium-high heat."
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Pour or scoop the batter onto the griddle, using"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "approximately 1/4 cup for each pancake; cook until"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "bubbles form and then flip. "
      />
       <TextInput
      placeholder = " "
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Step 3"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder = "Wait approximately 1 minute and serve with butter"
      />
      <TextInput
      placeholder =  "and warm maple syrup."
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
     flex: 1,
     paddingTop: 50,
     paddingBottom: 50,
    },
    itemName: {
      padding: 10,
      fontSize: 18,
      height: 44,
    },
    itemDesc: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 25,
        height: 44,
    },
      border: {
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: "blue",
      },
  });
  

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: Also, there are no references to any images or pictures in you posted code.

Comment: Are you looking for component to use a inage as background, then ImageBackground will work https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

Comment: I'm looking to insert the image so it shows up on the page. I didn't mean <TextInput> directly, but I didn't know how else to phrase it.